# Convert comma separated xml values into xml element and truncate unwanted data in the end

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xslt

I am very new to XML and XSL. 
This is my sample xml. I am trying to fetch few elements under CAR like `ID`, `Rating` and `Cost`, using this XSL.

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
     <SOMEDATA>
      <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
     </SOMEDATA>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="Car">
       <DATA>
     <xsl:copy-of select="Id"> </xsl:copy-of>
         <xsl:copy-of select="Cost"> </xsl:copy-of>
         <xsl:copy-of select="Rating"> </xsl:copy-of> 

         <xsl:template match="Rating">       
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(current(), ',')">
             <Rate>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
             </Rate>
        </xsl:for-each>
       </DATA>      
     </xsl:template>
```

=====INPUT====

```
--<MainXML>
----<Errors/>
--------<SubData>
-----------<CarData>

------------------<Cars>
---------------------<Car>
-----------------------<Id> 1</Id>
-----------------------<Name>ABC</Name>
-----------------------<Cost>100</Cost>
-----------------------<Rating> 4 star, 3 star, 2 star or similar </Rating>
---------------------<Car>

---------------------<Car>
-----------------------<Id> 2</Id>
-----------------------<Name>XYZ</Name>
-----------------------<Cost>200</Cost>
-----------------------<Rating> 5 star, 1 star or similar </Rating>
---------------------<Car>

---------------------<Car>
-----------------------<Id> 3</Id>
-----------------------<Name>DBC</Name>
-----------------------<Cost>800</Cost>
-----------------------<Rating> 2 star, 3 star or similar </Rating>
---------------------<Car>

------------------<Cars>
-----------<CarData>
--------<SubData>

--------<SubData1>
------------<SubDataRESULT1>
--------------------- <currecy>USD</currecy>
--------------------- <link> http://google.com </link>
--------------------- <Loca> XX </Loca>
--------------------- <Roca> uu </Roca>
------------<SubDataRESULT1>

------------<SubDataRESULT1>
--------------------- <currecy>EUR</currecy>
--------------------- <link> http://google.com </link>
--------------------- <Loca> UI </Loca>
--------------------- <Roca> RR </Roca>
------------<SubDataRESULT1>
--------<SubData1>

--------<SubData2> END1 </SubData2>
--------<SubData3> END2 </SubData3>
--<MainXML>
```

===Expected Output=====

```
--------<SOMEDATA>
----------------<DATA>
-----------------------<Id> 1</Id>
-----------------------<Cost>100</Cost>
-----------------------<Rating> 
---------------------------<Rate>4 star </Rate>
---------------------------<Rate>3 star </Rate>
---------------------------<Rate>2 star </Rate>
-----------------------<Rating> 
----------------<DATA>

----------------<DATA>
-----------------------<Id> 2</Id>
-----------------------<Cost>200</Cost>
-----------------------<Rating> 
---------------------------<Rate>5 star </Rate>
---------------------------<Rate>1 star </Rate>
-----------------------<Rating> 
----------------<DATA>

----------------<DATA>
-----------------------<Id> 3</Id>
-----------------------<Cost>800</Cost>
-----------------------<Rating> 
---------------------------<Rate>2 star </Rate>
---------------------------<Rate>3 star </Rate>
-----------------------<Rating> 
----------------<DATA>
--------<SOMEDATA>
```

===Actual Output=====

```
--------<SOMEDATA>
----------------<DATA>
-----------------------<Id> 1</Id>
-----------------------<Cost>100</Cost>
-----------------------<Rating> 4 star, 3 star, 2 star or similar </Rating>
-----------------------<Rating> 
----------------<DATA>

----------------<DATA>
-----------------------<Id> 2</Id>
-----------------------<Cost>200</Cost>
-----------------------<Rating> 5 star, 1 star or similar </Rating>
----------------<DATA>

----------------<DATA>
-----------------------<Id> 3</Id>
-----------------------<Cost>800</Cost>
-----------------------<Rating> 2 star, 3 star or similar </Rating>
----------------<DATA>
USDhttp://google.comXXuuEURhttp://google.comUIRREND1END2
--------<SOMEDATA>
```

Why is this part getting appended in the end. What am I missing?

```
USDhttp://google.comXXuuEURhttp://google.comUIRREND1END2
```

Also, How do I convert comma separated values into separate Elements by matching text and comma? Will tokenize not work in this case? Because I want to ignore `or similar` and consider only values before comma.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your input XML isn't a valid XML(missing proper end tags). After correcting it, you can use the following XSLT(version 2.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <SOMEDATA>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Car"/>
    </SOMEDATA>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Car">
    <DATA>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Id | Cost"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Rating"/>
    </DATA>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Rating">
    <Rating>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(current(), ',')">
            <Rate>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            </Rate>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Rating>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you are using XSLT 1.0, this would do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <SOMEDATA>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Car"/>
    </SOMEDATA>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Car">
    <DATA>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Id | Cost"/>
        <Rating>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="Rating"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="separator">,</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </Rating>
    </DATA>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
            <Rate>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
            </Rate>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <Rate>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
            </Rate>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you.. but I am getting "FATAL ERROR:  'Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(tokenize, [funcall(current, []), literal-expr(,)])'.'...And the other data is still getting added in the end

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using? tokenize() is available in 2.0.. If you are using 1.0, we would have to write a template to tokenize strings

Comment: I am using 2.0..Wonder why it is not working..Thanks for the help! I Appreciate it!

Comment: I guess your processor doesn't support 2.0.. I've edited my answer with 1.0 stylesheet.. That should help..